# Adjust first page offset in PDFView

Tags: ios, ios11, ios-pdfkit

I'm trying to build a small pdf viewer with PDFKit.
To achieve a parallax effect, I constrained the PDFView to the superview instead of the safe-area. Unfortunately the PDFView has the wrong offset inside it's ScrollView.

My idea: There should be a way to change the LayoutGuide or Safe-Area to make this properly.

[App screenshot with a misplaced pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIBKD.jpg)